# Deployed rails app on heroku and html code is appearing in my footer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

The problem is that when I sign in to my app and create a new post, all the html code shows next to delete button in footer. When I sign out, it does not show.It only appears when I am signed in. I am new to this and having hard time figuring it out. Does anyone know the reason why it is showng like this?

[image]

Comment: try to use `html_safe` method.  and next time post your code!)

Comment: yea Thanks for reply.  But i figured out the problem. it was simple syntax error when it suppose to be - if user_sigend_in?  but i had = if user_signed_in? . I am new to haml and learning the hard way!

Comment: @JonKim if you've solved your own question, it's helpful to other members of the community if you answer your own question, then mark your answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Im new to this so i wasn't aware. I figured it out and it was just a simple syntax error.